# How do I change the position of the Status Text in the status bar?

Tags: wxpython

I have a Line, Column status in my Status Bar and I'm wondering, how do I change the position of it to be the bottom right?

Code:

```
def StatusLineColumn(self, e):
     line = self.control.GetCurrentLine() + 1
     col = self.control.GetColumn(self.control.GetCurrentPos())
     stat = "Line %s, Column %s" % (line, col)
     self.StatusBar.SetStatusText(stat, 0)
```

I tried setting the position to a random position by doing self.SetPosition:

```
def Status_Bar(self):
    #Status Bar
    self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.StatusLineColumn(self)
    self.SetPosition(2, 2)
```

But it gave me this error: TypeError: Window.SetPosition(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the number of fields in the status bar and how they are mapped out, using `SetFieldsCount()` and `SetStatusWidths()`. The text is set using `SetStatusText("Text",n)` where `n` is the index of the field for the text.

Here is an example, where I set the 3rd field to be fixed length at 150 pixels wide and the other 2 (1st and 2nd) share the remaining space [-1,-1]:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import wx
import wx.stc
class TestWin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, ptitle):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 1, title = ptitle, size = (500, 300))

        menuFile = wx.Menu()
        menuFile.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Quit\tCTRL+q")

        self.control = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self,wx.ID_ANY,style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.VSCROLL)

        self.sbar = wx.StatusBar(self, 1)
        self.sbar.SetFieldsCount(3)
        self.sbar.SetStatusWidths([-1,-1,150])
        self.SetStatusBar(self.sbar)
        self.sbar.SetStatusText("First position",0)
        self.sbar.SetStatusText("Second position",1)
        self.sbar.SetStatusText("Third position",2)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
        self.Bind(wx.stc.EVT_STC_MODIFIED , self.StatusLineColumn, self.control)

    def StatusLineColumn(self, e):
        line = self.control.GetCurrentLine() + 1
        col = self.control.GetColumn(self.control.GetCurrentPos())
        stat = "Line %s, Column %s" % (line, col)
        self.sbar.SetStatusText("", 0)
        self.sbar.SetStatusText("", 1)
        self.sbar.SetStatusText(stat, 2)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Destroy()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        window = TestWin("Test Window")
        window.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(window)
        return True

app = App()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]